# Put two logos to the right side of the baposter

Tags: logos, baposter

There are two logos: `eyecatcher` on the left and logo on the right in the setting of `baposter`.
However, is it possible to put both TWO logos on the RIGHT side of `baposter`, with one on top of the other?

The following is the chunk of code

```
eyecatcher=false
% Eye Catcher Images to go left of your title.
{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{A.png}} %will not show if put eyecatcher=false
% Title
{\bf\textsc{POSTER TITLE}\vspace{0.5em}}
% Author
{\bf\textsc{AuthorName}}
% Logo
{\includegraphics[width=3in]{B.png}}
```

With the code, I can only show `B.png` on the top right of the poster. I want to put `A.png` on top of `B.png`, both on the top right side of the poster.

Comment: you can try with `\parbox{eyecatcher width}{\includegraphics{top image}\\ \includegraphics{bottom image}}`

Comment: @Ignasi Where should I place the code? I think the order matters. Simply replace `{\includegraphics[width=3in]{B.png}}` with yours gives error `Argument of \@iiiparbox has an extra }`.

Comment: Replace line after `%Logo` with `{\parbox{eyecatcher width}{\includegraphics{top image}\\ \includegraphics{bottom image}}}`

Comment: Got the multiple errors `Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Package calc Error: ``e' invalid at this point. Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`.

Comment: Please, add the code to your question. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. This way we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a tabular environment the following manner:

```
{\begin{tabular}{l}
\includegraphics[height=4em]{sponsorlogo1.eps}\\
\includegraphics[height=4em]{sponsorlogo2.png}
\end{tabular}
}  % Second university/lab logos on the right
```

In place of:

```
% Logo
{\includegraphics[width=3in]{B.png}}
```

Hopefully this works fine but I can provide more details if you wish.